# Why socket.emit not fired from React custom function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a custom function written to send messages from textarea when user presses 'enter' now from this function I am not able to do  `socket.emit('send-message', newMsg);`

This is inside the render():

```
<textarea name="txtArea" className="form-control mt-3 mb-3"  placeholder="Enter Message..(press enter to send)" onKeyPress={this.sendMessages.bind(this)}></textarea>
```

And the function is :

```
sendMessages(key){
    if(key.which === 13 && key.shiftKey === false){
        console.log(key.target.value);
        let newMsg = {
            message: key.target.value,
            from: this.state.currentUser
        }
        console.log(socket);
        socket.emit('send-message', newMsg);
    }
}
```

No idea why its not firing the socket.emit.

Thanks much for your time.

Comment: Found the answer I guess I had to use .preventDeafult in the end. ✌️

Comment: You might consider renaming your `key` argument to `e` or `event`, just to remind yourself that it is an event object being handled, the default action of which may or may not need to be blocked.